# Finding functions with integer coefficients that have imaginary zeros

Tags: functions

I'm preparing for the ACTM State contest, and I stumbled across this question:

Find a function with integer coefficients that has the zeros: 2 and 1-3i

I know how to find functions with certain zeros, but I'm not quite sure how to find ones with integer coefficients. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Hint: if a polynomial with real coefficients has a complex root, then its conjugate is also a root.

Comment: Okay, thanks! @dxiv

Answer (score 1):

The following polynomial satisfies the given conditions:
$$
(x-2)(x-1+3i)(x-1-3i) = x^3 - 4 x^2 + 14 x - 20.
$$